# How does updating rows from a subquery work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How does SQL Server know which rows to update when updating from a subquery rather than a table?

Say I have a table with three columns defined like below:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
   AId int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   AExternalId int NULL,
   ASequence int NULL
)
```

I want to update the column *ASequence* by sequential numbers within groups of *AExternalId* where *ASequence* is NULL.

For example, having inserted four different AExternalId's (or groups),

```
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1001)

INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1002)
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1002)

INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1003)
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1003)
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId]) VALUES (1003)

INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId], [ASequence]) VALUES (1004, 10)
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId], [ASequence]) VALUES (1004, 20)
INSERT INTO A ([AExternalId], [ASequence]) VALUES (1004, 30)
```

the table looks like this:

| AId | AExternalId | ASequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | NULL |
| 2 | 1002 | NULL |
| 3 | 1002 | NULL |
| 4 | 1003 | NULL |
| 5 | 1003 | NULL |
| 6 | 1003 | NULL |
| 7 | 1004 | 10 |
| 8 | 1004 | 20 |
| 9 | 1004 | 30 |

After the update, the table should look like this:

| AId | AExternalId | ASequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 |
| 2 | 1002 | 1 |
| 3 | 1002 | 2 |
| 4 | 1003 | 1 |
| 5 | 1003 | 2 |
| 6 | 1003 | 3 |
| 7 | 1004 | 10 |
| 8 | 1004 | 20 |
| 9 | 1004 | 30 |

*AId*s within every group of *AExternalId*'s now has a sequential number (except for the ones that already had a sequence).

I can achieve this by running the following query:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[ASequence] = t1.[CalcSequence]
FROM (
  SELECT AId, AExternalId, ASequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [AExternalId] ORDER BY [AExternalId], [AId] ASC) AS [CalcSequence]
  FROM [A]
  WHERE (ASequence IS NULL) AND (AExternalId IS NOT NULL)
) t1
```

The question is, why (or rather how) does this work as there is no table specified and no condition for the update?

I have been taught that an update without condition will update all rows in a table but in this case there is no table specified (only in the subquery).

Does this work because I am updating the resulting rows from the inner select? If so, how are rows "matched" so that the update is made on the correct row?

Is this an example of a *Correlated Subquery*?

I've tried to read up on those but failed to understand if this applies here. Many texts on Correlated Subqueries talk about performance issues and that *the correlated subquery requires values from its outer query* which does not seem to fit this example.

An alternative way of achieving the same result is by using an INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[ASequence] = t2.[CalcSequence]
FROM [A] t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AId, AExternalId, ASequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [AExternalId] ORDER BY [AExternalId], [AId] ASC) AS [CalcSequence]
  FROM [A]
  WHERE (ASequence IS NULL) AND (AExternalId IS NOT NULL)
) t2 ON t2.AId = t1.AId
```

I have compared the results of both queries and they are identical. Performance-wise, the first query *seems* to be a bit faster and consumes less resources.

The second query (with inner join) feels more "familiar", more "correct" but I would really like to understand how the first one works.

Comment: *"I have compared the results of both queries and they are identical."* If you look at the query plans, they will be quite different. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/49sXGIpD)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu! Yes, the query plans are different, I am not very skilled at interpreting them. What I meant was that end result, the table contents after running the two different updates, are identical. Didn't know about db<>fiddle, seems like a great resource!